# Bypassing a blocked port on a 3G connection

Tags: networking, wi-fi, vpn

I know this may seem illegal, but I just wanted to know how to bypass a blocked port on my Carrier 3G connection.

Sometime before I used to use some Android VPN app that gave me access to the Internet via my carrier, without Wi-Fi. I only use 3G data to connect to the internet and use all my apps, Facebook, Twitter and many others with no limits.

Then one day it stopped working and I couldn’t connect to the VPN server. I asked about it and I’ve been told that my carrier blocked the port I was using, and that it why I couldn’t use it anymore.

How does this port blocking work, and how can I bypass it, if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your carrier blocked the port. You cannot use it unless you can get the carrier to unblock it.

Comment: or use another port.

Comment: is there any way of knowing the possible port to use ?